# I need help retreiving all ['id']'s from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I need help with extracting all ['id'] values from a set of Arrays. The array array looks something like this:

```
    Array
    (
        [interests] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => daa4b58f91
                [list_id] => 6e9cb28acf
                [id] => b298c8dee6
                [name] => Feed 1
                [subscriber_count] => 1
                [display_order] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => daa4b58f91
                [list_id] => 6e9cb28acf
                [id] => 57ff19b511
                [name] => Feed 2
                [subscriber_count] => 1
                [display_order] => 2

            )
      ....

    etc.
```

The results I am trying to get is the values of the [id] in the second layer of Arrays, so it should return 'b298c8dee6' and '57ff19b511' in this case (of course the array is much longer in reality, that's why I want it to loop.

I've tried using a foreach loop, but I am not sure which values to use.

I'm hoping to get the values for each [id] in the array.

The code looked something like this, but it obviously didnt work

```
foreach($interest_group as $item) { 
    echo $item["id"]; 
}
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: There is no code yet, just the array, I need help with the loop.

Comment: _There is no code..._ But you said _I've tried using a foreach loop_

Comment: [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) can help you

Comment: 1) Please dont post code in comment, add it to your question. 2) Dont post code that ___looks something like this___ Post the ___REAL___ code. We cannot debug PSEUDO Code

Comment: `foreach($interest_group['interests'] as $item){  `

Comment: You main problem is that you are not accessing the array correctly.  `$interest_group` is your array but the data you want is in the next level down `interests`.  So in your loop you would use `$interest_group['interests']` to get to your data.

Comment: So really _this is a TYPO_

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [array_column](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function:
`$ids = array_column($your_array["interests"], 'id');`

Comment: I think `array_column($your_array["interests"], 'id');` will be better

Comment: Perfect, this is the answer I needed! Thanks

Comment: You are right, original post is badly formatted (I thought keys are "interests" and "1")

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon your description, following solution with PHP's in built function [array_column()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) will serve your requirement.

**NOTE:** But, this function will work for only if PHP >5.5.0, for versions older than it, it will throw Fatal Error.

Final Code:

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$arr['interests'] = [
 0 => [
  'category_id' => 'daa4b58f91',
  'list_id' => '6e9cb28acf',
  'id' => 'b298c8dee6',
  'name' => 'Feed 1',
  'subscriber_count' => 1,
  'display_order' => 1],
 1 => [
  'category_id' => 'daa4b58f91',
  'list_id' => '6e9cb28acf',
  'id' => '57ff19b511',
  'name' => 'Feed 2',
  'subscriber_count' => 1,
  'display_order' => 2
 ]
];
$ids = array_column($arr['interests'], 'id');
echo '<pre>';print_r($ids);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => b298c8dee6
    [1] => 57ff19b511
)
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!